# Creating title page with xcoffins

Tags: expl3, xcoffins

I want to create a title page like in the Tschichold example:

[image: title page]

using this code:

https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/l3experimental/xcoffins/xcoffins-tschichold-example.tex

in MiKTeX 2.8, but get the following message:

```
! Package expl3 Error: MismatchedLaTeX3packagesdetected..
```

I understand that MiKTeX has an issue with expl3 and xpackages and that I should use l3kernel and l3packages instead. So should I use the files provided at

https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/tree/master/l3experimental/xcoffins

and possibly the ones in testfiles? If so, how do I use them?

Comment: I think this message has reference to problems between LaTeX3 packages. They need to be updated together. Did you try to update them with MikTeX->Mateinance->Update?

Comment: I would try doing a synchronisation of the package database followed by an update. Do this both with the Admin and non-Admin versions of the manager.